# What does そうですね mean in this case?

Tags: grammar, particle-ね

> A : ..........でしょうか?
> B : そうですね, ............

In this case, そうですね means "Well" or そうです in softer version?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot tell the meaning of そうですね based on this alone. It depends on the context.

> A: これは何**でしょうか。**
> B: **そうですね**、何か料理に使う道具ですかね。

This そうですね is clearly "Well" or "Let's see".

> A: これはペン**でしょうか。**
> B: **そうですね**、どう見てもペンですね。

This そうですね is clearly "Yes".